# How to get GetFeatureInfoUrl from multiple layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have multiple layers in a map with layer group now onclick I want to get the GetFeatureInfoUrl for the different layers on which I am clicking but the problem is that I am getting only the Info for the last layer appended not the others.

Here is my code:

```
 var wms_layer;
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
        new ol.layer.Group({
            'title': 'Base maps',
            layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Water color',
                type: 'base',
                visible: false,
                source: new ol.source.Stamen({
                    layer: 'watercolor'
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'OSM',
                type: 'base',
                visible: true,
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    attributions: [
                    'All maps © <a href="https://www.opencyclemap.org/">OpenCycleMap</a>',
                    ol.source.OSM.ATTRIBUTION
                    ],
                    url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                })
            })
            ]
        }),
        new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Hisar Data Layers',
            layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Habitations',
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'http://192.168.2.2:8080/geoserver/HissarFullData/wms?service',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'HissarFullData:habitations',
                        'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    },
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            }),
           wms_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Hisar PWD',
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'http://192.168.2.2:8080/geoserver/HissarFullData/wms?service',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'HissarFullData:pwd',
                        'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    },
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                title: 'Hisar Block',
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: 'http://192.168.2.2:8080/geoserver/HissarFullData/wms?service',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': 'HissarFullData:block_boundary',
                        'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                    },
                    serverType: 'geoserver'
                })
            })
            ]
        })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.transform([75.7217, 29.1492], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            zoom: 10,
            minZoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 17
        })
    });
    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Layers' // Optional label for button
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
    var viewProjection = map.getView().getProjection();
    var viewResolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var url = wms_layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
            {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
            });
        if (url) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
            '<iframe style="width:100%;height:110px;border:0px;" id="iframe" seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
```

Whenever I click on the map I always getting info of the HissarFullData:block_boundary layer. I am using Layer switcher with this .

Comment: Try if adding &feature_count=10 helps. Have you checked that query has all the layers listed in &layers and in &query_layers? You can use Firebug or similar for that.

Comment: Hi let me check will ping back

Comment: @user30184 nothing changed.. in console it showing last year name only on click .. click function i have used is right ??

Comment: You must first make sure that you have a list of all layers in "layers" and "query_layers" in the request that your code generates. Something related in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24711/wms-getfeatureinfo-and-cql-on-multiple-layers.

Comment: @user30184 i have list of all layers now what to do next

Comment: Then it should just work and return a hit per layer if query finds a feature from the clicked place. I suppose you have also "habitations" and "pwd" in your query. The hint about feature_count was btw. wrong, default value 1 is OK: `The optional FEATURE_COUNT parameter states the maximum number of features per layer for which feature
information shall be returned. Its value is a positive integer. The default value is 1 if this parameter is omitted or is
other than a positive integer.`.

Comment: @user30184 Hi problem is with layer click ... whenver i am clicking it is only habitation layers..

Comment: Then you must build a list of layers on click. Can't help with javascript, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @user30184 in comments the important parameter here is `QUERY_LAYERS&`

To do a GetFeatureInfo request for multiple layers you need to list all those layers you want information on in the `QUERY_LAYERS&` parameter.

So consider these queries:

In this the [GetMap request](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.3249168839067,-10.3982024209475,61.0455548096319,3.17166214686146&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881&) is based on the *GBR_BGS_625k_BLS* layer `LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&` and the GetFeatureInfo request queries for information on the same layer `QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&`

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.3249168839067,-10.3982024209475,61.0455548096319,3.17166214686146&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881&I=736&J=652&info_format=text/html&QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&

In the next example the GetMap request is the same (it serves the purpose of providing an image to be used to provide an image coordinate `I=736&J=652&` but this time we want information for three layers `QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS,GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,GBR_BGS_625k_BLT&`

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.3249168839067,-10.3982024209475,61.0455548096319,3.17166214686146&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881&I=736&J=652&info_format=text/html&QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS,GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,GBR_BGS_625k_BLT&

You don't have to query the layer that is used to generate the GetMap request even, so GetMap is based on *GBR_BGS_625k_BLS*, but GetFeatureInfo is for *GBR_BGS_625k_SLT* and *GBR_BGS_625k_BLT*

http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_BLS&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.3249168839067,-10.3982024209475,61.0455548096319,3.17166214686146&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881&I=736&J=652&info_format=text/html&QUERY_LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,GBR_BGS_625k_BLT&

So in your example case if you want all layers to be queried independently of which WMS layer is clicked the code may look something like:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var url = wms_layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
            {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
                'QUERY_LAYERS': 'HissarFullData:block_boundary,HissarFullData:habitations,HissarFullData:pwd'
            });
        ...
```

Comment: how do you build this request using getGetFeatureInfoUrl? from what I can see  this can only be used with one source at a time.

Comment: A single GetFeatureInfo request can only be used against a single web service. You can though query multiple layers in that source.  If you have multiple sources (different services) then you'll need a different GFI for each source.  One way around this would be to set up you own WMS and cascade all your separate WMS sources through this, in other words create your own single source

Comment: ok thanks..I am hoping to find a way to solve the original question's problem from the front end, using Open Layers 3..I wont necessarily have control over the web map services

Comment: My get around option doesn't require you to have any control of the original services, just some server with WMS software configured.  The original question only references a single WMS source

Comment: I don't understand, the original question is about 'multiple layers', each one has same source url only, but different parameters. this is what I have as well.

Comment: A single WMS (a single source) may have multiple layers, in the question there is a single WMS (http://192.168.2.2:8080/geoserver/HissarFullData/wms?) and there are multiple layers (HissarFullData:habitations, HissarFullData:pwd, HissarFullData:block_boundary). A GFI request requires a GetMap request, and (in effect) appends a pixel coordinate and the layers to query. it doesn't matter if the actual GetMap request was for HissarFullData:habitations or HissarFullData:pwd or HissarFullData:block_boundary, the GFI may request that all of them are queried for the specified pixel coordinate.

Comment: yes, but when using getGetFeatureInfoUrl, only one layer is specified at a time, I am not seeing how to retrieve the properties for multiple layers and populate a single iframe with those values, as outlines in the original post. I'm missing something?

Comment: why can't you explicitly state the QUERY_LAYERS with multiple layers as a param, did you try it?

Comment: well, if you see the original post, the source is called as an property of a single layer when using getGetFeatureInfoUrl, as in '...wms_layer.getSource()...' ..i hope to build the request using this function.. ill look more into it, i am feeling pretty stuck though -  thanks for your help and patience btw!

Comment: For this to work, you'll also need  `FEATURE_COUNT` parameter set to the number of layers you want.

Comment: You don't need `feature_count`, the 2nd example request in the question gives three query layers and the request returns one feature from each layer in the response.  You only need `feature_count` if you want more than one feature per layer

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the LAYERS params if you want to filter your layers with QUERY_LAYERS, here is how i handle it

```
   clickHandler(event) {
    const viewResolution = this.mMap.getView().getResolution();
    const viewProjection = this.mMap.getView().getProjection();
    const { layers } = this.props
    var coordinate = event.coordinate;

    var url = ""
    let content = this.popupContent
    let popup = this.popup
    let queryLayers = ''

    if(layers){
        layers.forEach(function(lyr,i){
            queryLayers += `cahibi1:${lyr.Title}${(i<layers.length-1)?',' :''}`
        })
        console.log(queryLayers)
    }
    this.mMap.getLayers().forEach(function (lyr) {
        if (lyr.getSource()["getGetFeatureInfoUrl"] !== undefined) {

            url = lyr.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                coordinate, viewResolution, viewProjection,
                { 
                    'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html' ,
                    'QUERY_LAYERS':queryLayers,
                    'LAYERS':  queryLayers
                });
            console.log('url', url)
            if (url) {
                popup.setPosition(coordinate);
                content.innerHTML =
                    '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
            }
        }
    })
}
```